# Calling Java function defined in jsp via onclick

Tags: jsp

I want to call a java function when a row of my webpage is clicked.
I am not getting the correct syntax of calling it.
Or should i use javascript connectivity for my database if that is an appropriate method.?
I m using the following code:

```
<%
  try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lvcdatabase","root","mayank");
String query = "Select * from kitchentable;";
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs =pst.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()){
%>


   <form action="processorder" method="">
      <table id="example" >
      <%String s = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("orderno"));
        int i = rs.getInt("orderno");%>
        <tr id="row<%=s%>" onclick="a(<%=s%>)" onclick="update(<%=s%>)">

  onclick="<%update(s);%>" works but it calls java function when page is loaded everytime. Onclick loses its significance...


          <td><%=rs.getInt("orderno")%></td>
          <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
          <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
          <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
          <td><input class="service" id="service<%=s%>" onclick="b(<%=s%>)" type="button" value="Service Status"></td>
         </tr>




         <tr id="buttonrow">
           <td colspan="1"></td>
           <td colspan="1"><input type="button" style="background-color:#ff0000" value="Pending" id="redbutton<%=s%>" class="statusbutton"></td>
           <td colspan="1"><input type="button" style="background-color:#ffbf50" value="Cooking" id="amberbutton<%=s%>" class="statusbutton"></td>
           <td colspan="1"><input type="button" style="background-color:##e5ffe5" value="Cooked" id="greenbutton<%=s%>" class="statusbutton"></td>
           <td colspan="1"></td>

         </tr>


   </form><br>
   <%} %>
   </table>
   <%rs.close();
   pst.close();
   conn.close();
   }catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    %>
```

My java function

```
   <%!public void update(String f){
    String l = f;

   new BusinessFunctions().updateStatus(l);
   }
   %>
```

Comment: You have to learn the difference in where is which code executed: JSP is executed **on server** and generates HTML (and JavaScript etc.), which then runs **in browser**. If you need to call server-side code from browser, use [AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onclick` is client side event.

You can only specify any javascript function, from which you can call any server side(JSP/Servlet) method via AJAX.

or, You can construct an url in onclick like:

```
 <a href="/yoururl?id="+<%=s%>>Order No</a>
```

and from this you can call a server side method.